# "The codesign tool could not be found" from Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode5, codesign

I'm trying to **generate an IPA** file for my App from **Xamarin Studio**, on Mac, and i'm getting this error:

***"The codesign tool could not be found"***

I checked the certificates, provisioning profiles, etc. I generated apps before in this machine, using the same developer account.

From Terminal i can see that codesign command is being recognized, but maybe Xamarin Studio is looking for it in a different place.

**Similar problem in XCode**

I tried to generate the IPA from a random project in XCode and it gave me a similar error:

***"can't exec 'codesign'"***

Then i found an issue on stackoverflow that said to copy the codesign program from /usr/bin to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/bin

I did that and everything worked fine in XCode, but still getting the same error from Xamarin Studio.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about xamarin, but chances are you don't have command line tools installed. Go to preferences and downloads. I think it comes standard with Xcode 5 now, but maybe not.

Comment: thanks for replying. Command line tools is installed, in addition, i was able to generate the ipa via the command xcrun, but since it was done outside Xamarin Studio, i'm not sure if it's 100% functional, haven't had the chance to test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since i was totally out of time, and needed a workaround, i reinstalled the OS and all the tools, and it did the job for me.

I'm sorry i couldn't get to a more concrete solution for this problem.